# Camera photo selection not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Why isn't the second function being called when the user takes the photo and clicks the use photo button? The view gets dismissed, but the print statement doesn't work and the function isn't called.

```
@IBAction func openCamera(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        print("made it")
        createImage(image: image)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
```

Comment: Did you make the view the delegate? Do you have **imagePicker.delegate = self** someplace (probably viewDidLoad)?

Comment: in first method @dfd

Comment: Sorry, missed that. the only other thing I see is this your second override. Are you using Swift 3? If so, it's **func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {**

Comment: yes I am using swift 3. thanks @dfd

Comment: I'll throw my code into an answer. You pretty much have it correct now as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Swift 3, here's what I have. My code is meant to have (1) a select view controller, which uses the UIImagePickerController to either use the camera or select from the camera roll, then (2) sequel to an edit view controller I stripped out the code for the buttons, as I'm not using IB.

```
class SelectViewController: UIViewController {

    // selection and pass to editor

    let picker = ImagePickerController()
    var image = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
    }

extension SelectViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Camera App

    func openCameraApp() {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            present(picker,
                    animated: true,
                    completion: nil)
        } else {
            noCamera()
        }
    }
    func noCamera(){
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(
            title: "No Camera",
            message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
            preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style:.default,
            handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        present(
            alertVC,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Photos Albums

    func showImagePicker() {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(picker,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        image = chosenImage
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowEditView", sender: self)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Seque to EditViewController

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowEditView" {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? EditViewController {
                vc.image = image
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you aren't segueing to another VC, remove the **.performSegue** call and the code below the the final MARK: notation. (The camera/selected image is in the **image** var.)